# How to translate this SQL query to DB::getInstance() class?

Tags: php, mysql

Prestashop 1.6.0.13
Theme: Panda 1.1.1 (Themeforest)

I'm trying to develop a web that change the prices in real time.

This is the process:

After the web is loaded, this jquery is executed.

```
     $('#divId').load('../../price.php');
    setInterval(function(){
        $('#divId').load('../../price.php');
}, 3600);
```

That call this price.php

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("https://gold-feed.com/paid/38940e/all_metals_json_eur.php");
$obj = json_decode($data, true);
$a = $obj['gold_ask_eur_toz'];
echo $a."    ".time();

/*
$name = 10;
Db::getInstance()->insert('ps_54z_product_shop', array(
    'price'      => pSQL($name),
));
*/
?>
```

The first part calls a JSON file which contains the live prices. 
I know that this bit works.

The las bit doesn't work for me. The SQL query in MySQL

```
UPDATE `ps_54z_product_shop` SET `price`= 10
```

Works perfectly.

How I can do to translate this query

```
UPDATE `ps_54z_product_shop` SET `price`= 10
```

to Db::getInstance() and put it in a php file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an update, you should use the update function:

```
Db::getInstance()->update('ps_54z_product_shop', array('price' => pSQL($name)), '1'); 
//Replace 1 by "some_id=$id" something
```

You'll need to get the 3rd parameter right, the where part... As you did not mention any, I've put 1 this will update the whole table to reflect your code, but I'm sure it is not what you want.

Read more about the update function at http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/DB+class+best+practices#DBclassbestpractices-update()

Also note that you can simply run a query, at least while prototyping if it let's you go faster using the execute() function.